# Ошибка сегементации в CLion

Tags: c++

При простой работе с вектором возникает ошибка сегментации.Чем это вызвано? Ошибка возникает при вызове первой функции копирования. Результатом должно стать копирование содержимого вектора и вывод его на экран с помощью потокового итератора

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
int main() {
std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
const int size=10;
vector<int> dice1={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
vector<int> dice[size];
ostream_iterator<int,char> outer_iter(cout," ");
copy(dice1.begin(),dice1.end(),dice->begin());
copy(dice->begin(),dice->end(),outer_iter);

return 0;


}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Следует указать на какой строке происходит ошибка, привести стек вызовов, а также ожидаемый результат от выполняемой на тот момент операции.

Answer (score 2):

`vector<int> dice[size];` - это у вас массив из десяти пустых векторов. А много информации записывать в пустой вектор вызывает ошибку.
Нужно было создать **один** вектор с нужной длиной.

```
vector<int> dice(size);
..
copy(dice1.begin(),dice1.end(),dice.begin());
copy(dice.begin(),dice.end(),outer_iter);
```

Comment: Ну вот, все заспойлерено... У человека был шанс самостоятельно разобраться с такой пустяковой проблемой и чуть-чуть апнуть навык отладки, стоило только подтолкнуть его в верном направлении. А так в следующий раз он опять запутается в трех березах и побежит на SO плодить бестолковые вопросы.